# Adding Gtk+ app to launcher upon installation

Tags: gtk

How can I modify the source code of my GTK+ application in such manner, so that when I install it using the regular commands `make`, `make install` , `./configure` to appear at the applications menu instead of having to type it's name at terminal?

By no means I am using Quickly.

Reffering to the answer below, how can this be done automatically and not manualy?

Comment: The desktop entry is not written "automatically". You write a template of it and substitute variables that need to be substituted if any (autoconf, automake, cmake, etc.; can help with this). And finally you make sure `make install` puts the desktop entry in `/usr/share/applications` (more generally, in `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications` as [specified by freedesktop.org](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should create a `.desktop` file, and install it in `/usr/share/applications` (or `~/.local/share/applications` or more generally `$datadir/applications`).

Study the contents of `/usr/share/applications` and read [Recognized desktop entry keys](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html).